# How to apply a theme/styling to ActionMenuView?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-toolbar

I'm using the new `android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView` (v7, r21) to mimic a split action bar in my application. My top toolbar is themed with `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar`, so its text and overflow icon appear white. The ActionMenuView content however appears black, is there a way to apply the theme there as well or at least color the option items text white?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:support="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/bar_action"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    support:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    support:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/bar_split"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

Comment: May I ask an unrelated question: Is your `ActionMenuView` showing things with width set to `match_parent`? I am experiencing this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78364

Comment: The widget seems pretty flawed, I encountered some issues where it wouldn't show up for me as well. And I can't event determine why it's working for me right now. I startet with putting it at the proper position, but it didn't show up. So I put it somewhere in my content layout just to give it a shot, and it was right there. Then I styled it, did my coding and put it back to where it belongs, and it's still working. Probably magic involved.

Comment: It's also giving no damn about my layout_height attribute. As soon as I'm inflating a menu it changes its height to whatever it's up to...

Comment: Right, ok, I'll try to move the widget around a bit. ;)

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I'm using a Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar theme for the activity. The ActionMenuView overflow icon appears white (as intended) only on API21 when using android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar". Using support:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" doesn't work. I only ever get a dark icon on pre-API21 no matter what ActionMenuView theme I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me, didn't define `android:textColorPrimary` in my theme!